# asp.net mvc 3 changes made in Controller files are not reflected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC3, I got simple work to add a page in already existing web site.

Any changes made in Controller files are not reflected. Even I renamed Controller folder to Controller1 etc.. but site is working perfectly!!! Rally Sucks.
But renaming Views and other folders throw errors.

Am I doing anything wrong? Any Helps are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Since ASP.NET MVC uses an ASP.NET web application model if you change the code in your controllers you should recompile your project for changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. How recompile my project using Visual Web Developer? or is there any other alternative way to do it?

Comment: Do you have a Build -> Build [yourproject] menu?

Comment: What is not working? What exactly have you done? What error are you getting? Please provide more details.

Comment: All I want to add a page called Map in a MVC3 project. I tried to create controller called MapController.cs and a View. Then I hit build. When I tried to access http://localhost:2202/Map its showing 

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.

Comment: Did you add an action inside this `MapController`? Like for example: `public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }`. Then did you add a corresponding view in the correct location which is `~/Views/Map/Index.cshtml` (and **not** `~/Views/MapController/Index.cshtml`)? Does your `MapController` class inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`? Have you modified your routing configuration? If yes, how do they look like? Also you mentioned that you are navigating to `http://localhost:2202/Map`. In this url you haven't specified an action name. Only the controller. ...

Comment: ... so if your controller doesn't have a default action as configured in your routes (by default it is the `Index` action) this won't work.

Comment: yes I added actions inside MapController also added corresponding view in the correct location (~/Views/Map/Index.cshtml).Also I tried to add new action inside AboutController (Controller already existing in this project). I added following action
public ActionResult Mymap(){
            return View();
        }
but I'm getting same error.

Comment: What about your routes? What happens when you navigate to `http://localhost:2202/Map/Index` (assuming you have added `public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }` inside your `MapController`)? What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: this is error message I'm getting when navigate to http://localhost:2202/Map/Index

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Map/Index

Comment: You didn't answer my question about how your routing setup look like in Global.asax.

Comment: and this is the routing inside global.asax.cs

 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

Comment: Alright, so you seem to be using the default routes. Another question: does the `MapController` class derive from `Controller`, i.e. `public class MapController: Controller { public ActionResult Index() { return View(); } }`.

Comment: Then this should work. Try creating this in a new ASP.NET MVC application. You must have messed something up.

Comment: yeah your are right. I already tested new MVC application its working fine. This whole work done by another programmer. all changes in Views work fine but even is there any syntax errors in Controller project running fine and showing no errors. Its not checking any controllers I think.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest dll and pdb files loaded in the bin directory on the **server** for your project.

E. G. [on the server ...] D:\MyProjectFolder\bin\myProject.dll 
E. G. [on the server ...] D:\MyProjectFolder\bin\myProject.pdb